# Copy row from one table to other in the editable text box

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I want to copy row from one table to other table if the check box is selected in first table. I am able to copy data with the help of below code. But the problem is I want the data in the editable text box, so that I can edit the copied data. Please help me.. I have tried to search a lot but could not find anything useful.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#add').on("click", function()  {
        var copiedRow = $('#table1 tbody input:checked').parent().parent().clone();
        $('#table2 tr:first').after(copiedRow);
    });
});
```

So here is code from JSP table1

```
 <c:if test="${!empty asilList}">
      <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>HARA ID</th>
          <th>Vehicle Condition(V)</th>     
          <th>Environmental Condition(E)</th>
          <th>Driving Conditions</th>
          <th>Scenario</th>     
          <th>E</th>
          <th>Situation/Condition for Exposure</th>
          <th>C</th>        
          <th>Controllability</th>
          <th>S</th>
          <th>Severity</th>     
          <th>ASIL</th>
          <th>Remarks</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${asilList}" var="a" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            <td>${a.haraId}</td>
                            <td>${a.scenario.vehicleCondition.vehicleCondition}</td>
                            <td>${a.scenario.environmentalCondition.environmentalCondition}</td>
                            <td>${a.scenario.drivingCondition.drivingCondition}</td>
                            <td>${a.scenario.scenario}</td> 
                            <td>${a.exposure.exposure}</td>
                            <td>${a.exposure.remark}</td>
                            <td>${a.controllability.controllability}</td>
                            <td>${a.controllability.remark}</td>
                            <td>${a.severity.severity}</td>
                            <td>${a.severity.remark}</td>
                            <td>${a.asil}</td>
                            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </table>
      </c:if>
```

table2

```
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>HARA ID</th>
      <th>Vehicle Condition(V)</th>     
      <th>Environmental Condition(E)</th>
      <th>Driving Conditions</th>
      <th>Scenario</th>     
      <th>E</th>
      <th>Situation/Condition for Exposure</th>
      <th>C</th>        
      <th>Controllability</th>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>Severity</th>     
      <th>ASIL</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Vehicle Conditions">
                  </optgroup>
                </select></td>
            <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Environmental Conditions">
                  </optgroup>
                </select></td>
            <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Driving Conditions">
                  </optgroup>
                </select></td>
            <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Scenarios">
                  </optgroup>
                </select></td>

            <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Exposure">
                  </optgroup>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Controllability">
                  </optgroup>
                 </select></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>        
      <td><select>
                  <optgroup label="Severity">
                  </optgroup>
                 </select></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>      
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: write $('#table1 tbody input:checked').parent().parent() to console and be sure if it comes right

Comment: @AnovaConsultancy Thanks for your immediate reply. I think you misunderstood my question. I am able to copy the data with my code. But I want this data in the text boxes in the second table. So that i can edit (if i want) in the second table.

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information to answer your question accurately. I am just guessing with my solution. You said you wanted the row to be copied to an editable textbox and from your code it looks like you want that code in the second row of the second table. So here you go https://jsfiddle.net/v5agtrpv/

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#add').on("click", function()  {
        $('#table2 tbody').empty();
        var $newrow,
            $newcolumn;
        $('#table1 tbody input:checked').parent().parent().each(function() {
            $newrow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($('#table2 tbody'));
            $("td", this).each(function() {
                if($("input", this).length == 0) {
                    $newcolumn = $("<td><input type='text' /></td>").appendTo($newrow);
                    $("input", $newcolumn).val($(this).text());
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am copying a row having 14 columns at the rowIndex[1] in the table2. and the table2 does not having any pre-existing text boxes. So what I want is : creating dynamically a row with 14 columns having text boxes in table2 and copy data from table1 to table2 in those text boxes. Hope I am clear.

Comment: ok, i updated it to copy each row html from table 1 and format them into each a seperate colun in table 2, inside of textboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your so far help. With your script i am getting all the 14 columns data in one text box only. and the data having <td></td> tags with it.. Could you solve this problem please

Comment: to clarify: You just want the text of each checked row from table1? BTW: there is already a separate textbox for each column. Take a look again

Comment: yes you are right i want text of each checked row from table1. But each row has around 14 columns. And with your script I can copy only first column data from each row. To be clear: It is generating only one text box for each row, But it should generate 14 columns for each row in table2.

Comment: ok, what i updated doesn't matter how many rows and how many columns it has in the first table. It will copy all to a second table EXCEPT the checkbox. With this code you should be able to do exactly what you want. It might now be completely there based on the information you've given me so for but small tweaks would be all that you need.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#add').on("click", function()  {
        var copiedRow = $('#table1 tbody input:checked').parent().parent().clone();
  var firstRow = $(copiedRow).find('td span:eq(0)').text();
  $('#table2 tbody').append(copiedRow)
  
  $('#table2 tbody tr td:eq(1)').empty().append('<input type="text" value="'+firstRow+'">')

  
  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table1">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="add" /></td>
   <td><span>Php</span></td>
   <td><span>Jquery</span></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <table class="table" id="table2">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is not what I want :(

Comment: @Ishan okay, from your question I guessed this is what you want. Hope someone will help you better. Enjoy coding